# How to access keys in a dictionary with multiple values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

This is a code to return the keys of a dicitionary having "10" in their values.

```
word_freq = {'is': [1, 3, 4, 8, 10],
         'at': [3, 10, 15, 7, 9],
         'test': [5, 3, 7, 8, 1],
         'this': [2, 3, 5, 6, 11],
         'why': [10, 3, 9, 8, 12]}
# Check if a value exist in dictionary with multiple value
value = 10
# Get list of keys that contains the given value
  list_of_keys = [key
            for key, list_of_values in word_freq.items()
            if value in list_of_values]
if list_of_keys:
   print(list_of_keys)
else:
   print('Value does not exist in the dictionary')
```

**Output**:  `['is', 'at', 'why']`

I want to modify it to look for multiple values like "10" and "3" and return keys having any of these numbers in their values.

Please suggest a solution

Comment: Look at `or` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) or [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) based on your use case:

```
values = [10, 3, 9]
# Get list of keys that contains the given value
list_of_keys = [key
            for key, list_of_values in word_freq.items()
            if all(val in list_of_values for val in values)]

list_of_keys = [key
            for key, list_of_values in word_freq.items()
            if any(val in list_of_values for val in values)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use value as an array instead of a single number.

```
word_fre[q = {'is': [1, 3, 4, 8, 10],
         'at': [3, 10, 15, 7, 9],
         'test': [5, 3, 7, 8, 1],
         'this': [2, 3, 5, 6, 11],
         'why': [10, 3, 9, 8, 12]}
# Check if a value exist in dictionary with multiple value
value = [10]
# Get list of keys that contains the given value
list_of_keys = []
for i in value:
    for key, list_of_values in word_freq.items():
        if i in list_of_values:
            list_of_keys.append(key)
    
if list_of_keys:
   print(set(list_of_keys))#this gives all the values only once
else:
   print('Value does not exist in the dictionary')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `intersection()`:

```py
word_freq = {'is': [1, 3, 4, 8, 10],
         'at': [3, 10, 15, 7, 9],
         'test': [5, 3, 7, 8, 1],
         'this': [2, 3, 5, 6, 11],
         'why': [10, 3, 9, 8, 12]}
# Check if a value exist in dictionary with multiple value
values = {10, 3}
# Get list of keys that contains the given value
  list_of_keys = [key
            for key, list_of_values in word_freq.items()
            if values.intersection(set(list_of_values))]
if list_of_keys:
   print(list_of_keys)
else:
   print('Values does not exist in the dictionary')
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working fine. Fine tune it as per requirement.

```
word_freq = {'is': [1, 3, 4, 8, 10],
         'at': [3, 10, 15, 7, 9],
         'test': [5, 3, 7, 8, 9],
         'this': [2, 3, 5, 6, 11],
         'why': [10, 3, 9, 8, 12]}

value = [10, 1]

out = []

for check_val in value :
  print("\nChecking for value : ", check_val)
  for key in word_freq.keys() :
    print("Checking for key : " , key)
    if check_val in word_freq[key] :    
      out.append(key)
  print(out)

print("Final keyset : ", set(out))
```

**OUTPUT** for the same :

[image]